Issues Modifying Cobblemon Mod for Minecraft Version 1.20.4 Using IntelliJ IDEA
I'm working with the Cobblemon Minecraft plugin, which supports version 1.20.1 under both Forge and Fabric. The mod's repository is located at: https://gitlab.com/cable-mc/cobblemon/
I downloaded the source and attempted to modify it for Minecraft version 1.20.4 using IntelliJ IDEA. I made changes to the following files to adapt the code:
gradle.properties: https://pastes.dev/RzYWxGjnyA
libs.versions.toml: https://pastes.dev/4P6TV1oGdh
However, when I build the project, I encounter the following error: https://pastes.dev/WSoAmVLp5o
As I'm not a Java developer by trade, I've done my best with the modifications, but I'm stuck at this point. Could someone please help me understand what's going wrong and how I might resolve this issue?

Instead of posting links to files containing text, please add the relevant text directly into the body of your question, with appropriate formatting.

This is a (partial) list of errors your code now has after switching the Minecraft version and intended behavior. Go through this list and fix them, and at the end of the day you will understand why mod developers hate porting.
